# CSS: How do you change the color of the "check" within an HTML checkbox?

Tags: html, css

How do you change the color of the "check" within an HTML checkbox?

By default, on WinXP Firefox/Chrome/IE - the check is green. I would like to change the check within an `INPUT type="checkbox"` to orange

Answer (score 7):

There's no way to do this consistently with stock `input`s. Safari, for one, will never respect your tweaks.

You can use JavaScript to present styled elements that function as checkboxes. [Here's one plugin that uses jQuery](http://www.queness.com/post/204/25-jquery-plugins-that-enhance-and-beautify-html-form-elements#5).

Comment: +1 for right answer and suggesting workarounds; I believe checkbox color is an OS setting, rather than an HTML or CSS or even browser setting.

Comment: Scrollbars are also OS objects, but they're stylable.

Comment: Not in all browsers, they're not.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, this isn't particularly easy to do in a cross-browser way.

But another possibility is [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) which is highly customizable.  You can even [design a theme](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) on their site.  And along with all that you can use the [jQuery UI Checkbox](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ui-checkbox).

You could potentially roll your own lighter-weight version of all this with a combination of Javascript and CSS.  But I imagine you'd run into a lot of compatibility issues that have already been figured out by the jQuery guys.

Answer (score -2):

```
<style>input[type=checkbox] { background-color: #F00; color: #0F0; } </style>
<input type="checkbox" CHECKED>
```

This is not a cross-browser solution (hey, IE!). Here's a more portable one:

```
<style> input.checkbox { background-color: #F00; color: #0F0; } </style>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" CHECKED>
```